# How to post the 'token' response object to get the view of Tableau from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm posting some data via Ajax call and getting the 'TOKEN' after getting the response object in turn should post to another URL to get the view of Tableau in `<iframe>`. Below is my code and error:

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Tableau Template</title>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Tableau Template</title>

    <!-- Vendor Script -->


    <!-- Commmon Script -->
    <script>
      function getTicket() {
        try {

          alert("Get Ticket");

          var tableauInfo = {
            username: "10162492",
            site_root: "POC1",
            // client_ip:"66.145.223.55"
          }

          //$('#getTicket').html('sending..');
          var dashboardResourceURL = "https://analytics.xxxxxxxxxxxx/trusted/##TOKEN##/t/POC1/views/ExampleVis/Dashboard1?:iid=1"
          var resourceURL = "https://xxxxxxxxxx/ticket1.php"



          $.ajax({
              method: 'POST',
              url: resourceURL,
              // data: JSON.stringify(tableauInfo),
              dataType: 'json',
              contentType: 'text/html',
              headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description"
              },
              crossDomain: true,
            })
            .success(function(result) {

              console.log(result);
              alert(Json.stringify(result));
              dashboardResourceURL.replace("##TOKEN##", result);
              alert(dashboardResourceURL);
              $('#tokenurl').show();
              $('#tokenurl').src = dashboardResourceURL;
              $('#getTicket').html(data.msg);

              return result;
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
              console.log('failed!! ', data);

              $('#getTicket').html("Error retrieving ticket from Tableau server");

            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('an unforseen error occurred; it is ', err);
        }


      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3>Tableau Ticket</h3>
      <br />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="getTicket();">Get Tableau
        Ticket</button>
      </div>
      <br /> <br />
      <div id="getTicket"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="tokenurl" src="" style="display: none;"> </iframe>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> Error: failed!! Object { readyState=4,  responseText="ARCIMBGAn1wNxxu3932mJ8GW",  status=200,  more...}

Please let me what I'm missing here..

Comment: You should post your full error statement

Comment: please add all inside `console.log(data)`

Comment: Problem resolved...